# strncpy and strcat usage

Tags: c, string, syntax

My homework requires that my name be displayed such that it looks like this: '**Lastname, Firstname**'. Last name then [comma space] firstname. While not moving over the rest of the text after that name. This is my code:

```
  char str1[11];
  char str2[3];
  char str3[16];
  strcpy (str1,fn);
  strcpy (str2,", ");
  strcpy (str3,ln);
  strncat (str1, str2, 14);
  strncat (str1, str3, 31);
```

My teacher said that I did what he wanted, but he doesn't like how many lines of code I used and said I am doing extra work than I need.

Variables: `ln = last name`, `fn = first name` I made str2 for the ', ' comma space.

What is it that he wants me to do?

Comment: What types are ln and fn?  Why can't you just use them?

Comment: Do you have to use `strcpy` and `strncat`? Check out `sprintf` if not!

Comment: They are char[size].

Comment: You don't need to allocate 3 separate buffers for the final string. You can just allocate a single buffer and then strcat strings to it. e.g. `strcat(str1, ", ");`. Alternatively, you could use sprintf.

Comment: Also, you should assure that str1 is the correct size. str1 is 11 bytes, but you are calling strncat with 31 bytes as the max length parameter. From the Linux man pages: "the size of dest must be at least strlen(dest)+n+1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char result[50];

strcpy(result, ln);
strcat(result, ", ");
strcat(result, fn);
```

He's right, you used way too many statements (and wasted too much memory doing it).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you know length of strings, why not do

```
char result[50];

sprintf(result,"%s, %s",ln, fn);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is all you need:

```
strcpy (str1,ln);    // Copy the last name to str1
strcat (str1,", ");  // Now append ", " to the last name in str1
strcat (str1,fn);    // Lastly, append the first name to str1
```

You must make sure that `str1` is large enough to hold all of that. An array of 13 characters may not be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your `strcpy` calls are really unnecessary since you already have first name and last name in variables. You can just create a buffer big enough to hold the entire string then use `strcat` to create the final "lastname, firstname" string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised your instructor accepted your answer.  You are accumulating your result in the char array str1, which you've declared has only 11 characters.  Unless `strlen(ln)+strlen(fn)<=8`, you will overflow the space you've allocated for the result `str1`.  In the bad old days, a C programmer would have simply allocated a result array that seemed big enough, and not bothered to check.  The standard C library function `sprintf` in `stdio.h` is designed for this job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
...fn, ln defined...
char result[80];  /* 80 characters is probably enough */
sprintf(result, "%s, %s", ln, fn);
```

A modern C programmer would never assume that `ln` and `fn` were short enough not to overflow a result array, no matter how long.  The safe, modern alternative would be to replace the `sprintf` call by `snprintf`:

```
snprintf(result, 80, "%s, %s", ln, fn);
```

You can also use the `strcpy`/`strcat` family of functions, which are in `string.h`. (Was this specified in your assignment?)  The safe, modern equivalents are `strncpy` and `strncat`, which let you specify a maximum number of characters to copy.  A quick and dirty but safe solution using these functions would be:

```
char result[80];
result[0] = '\0';     /* initialize result to "" */
strncat(result, ln, 40);
strcat(result, ", ")  /* you know this adds exactly two characters */
strncat(result, fn, 38);
```

The `strncpy` call is dangerous because it may not leave a null-terminated string in `result`, which will cause a subsequent `strcat` to fail.  This isn't many fewer lines than what you did, but using just these `string.h` functions, it's tough to do much better and be guaranteed you can't overflow the result buffer no matter what `ln` and `fn` are given.